# How would I convert the minutes column of a pandas dataframe that goes above 59 to a proper datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that has 2 columns: The first column is the minutes, and the second column is the seconds. It looks like this:

```
     min   s
0      0   0
1      0   1
2      0   2
3      0   3
4      0   4
5      0   5
6      0   6
7      0   7
8      0   8
9      0   9
10     0  10
11     0  11
12     0  12
```

I can convert this to datetime by:

```
l = []
for MinSec in list(zip(df['min'],df['s'])):
    l.append(':'.join(map(str,MinSec)))

pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(l), format='%M:%S')
```

However, when the min column reaches 59, it continues to count upwards (60, 61, 62, etc.). This throws an error:

```
ValueError: time data '60:0' does not match format '%M:%S' (match)
```

How would I handle this error and successfully join the above two column pandas dataframe to datetime?

Comment: Maybe a step before to add an hours column. You could use modulo and / or division to get hours out of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the total number of seconds :

```
df['total_second']=60.*df['min']+df['s']
```

Then you can convert it to Datetime :

```
pd.to_datetime(df['total_second'], unit='s')
```